# jQuery append input value to iframe data-src

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, iframe

How can I append an input value to data-src iframe in jQuery.

```
var input = $("#input").val();

var iframe = $(".win");
iframe.attr("src", iframe.data("src").join(input)); 
        
console.log(iframe.data("src"));
```

I am doing like the above snippet but the console.log returns only the initial value without the input value that should be appended.

Does anyone know a way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not update `data-src`. You updated `src` attribute.

```
var input = $("#input").val();

var iframe = $(".win");
iframe.attr("src", iframe.data("src").join(input)); 
    
console.log(iframe.attr("src"));
console.log(iframe.data("src"));
```

Comment: isn't that the same as I have?

Comment: I mean, you updated iframe `src' attribute. But you did log iframe 'data-src'.

Comment: `console.log(iframe.data("src"));` is your code. 
But you updated `iframe.attr("src", ...`

Comment: Oh that's right... Got it! I was doing it in the right way but logging the wrong data.